# Determine how many time a Day occurs between two days in Java

Tags: java

I need to calculate how many times a Day occurs between two dates, which can be weekly or monthly.

Eg Monthly:
StartDate : 2019/01/29
EndDate: 2019/03/28

So considering the above example, the output should be 1, as this is not a leap year, Feb(28) days, also it ends on March 28.

```
int recordCountMonths = (int) ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(scheduleStartDate, scheduleEndDate);

int recordCountWeeks = (int) ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(scheduleStartDate, scheduleEndDate);
```

Exmaple 1
The Months implementation gives me 2 (it should return 3, considering leap year) if my date is between:

```
 LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 29);

LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.APRIL, 28);
```

Example2:
The Months implementation gives me 3 (it should return 2, considering 31 occurs in Jan and March only) if my date is between:

```
  LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 31);

    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MAY, 28);
```

Also, the above count can be asked to calculate weekly too. In that case the count will be more. However, lets not focus on weekly for now.

I can't think of a simple way to do this.

I have tried different ways, but that gives me inaccurate results.

Comment: Please post that code that gave you inaccurate results.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Are you asking how to calculate the months (or weeks) between two dates?  Do you mean *full* months (or weeks), or partials?

Comment: I have updated my question with code

Comment: `ChronoUnit.between` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Read its documentation. You want to get how many times a day-of-the-month occurs between two dates, correct? `between` does not do that, it only tells you the full units of time between those two dates.

Comment: Thats correct. I am thinking of a better way to do this and not have complex logic around months and year.

Comment: I'll whip something up. `between` is definitely not the way to go about it though.

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here's a method to solve your problem. It could be better but this should work well enough. You can make similar counting methods for other specific cases, like whatever you wanted to do with weeks.

```
/**
 * Returns the count of the day of the start day of the month between start and end inclusively.
 */
public static int getCountOfDayOfMonthBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    // the target day of the month to count
    final int dom = start.getDayOfMonth();

    // 'start' is counted as a valid day
    int count = 1;
    LocalDate currDate = start.plusMonths(1);
    while (!currDate.isAfter(end)) {
        try {
            currDate = currDate.withDayOfMonth(dom);
            // day of month changed, so check that the date is still valid
            if (currDate.isAfter(end)) {
                return count;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        }
        currDate = currDate.plusMonths(1);
    }
    return count;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate start1 = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 29);
    LocalDate end1 = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.APRIL, 28);
    System.out.println(getCountOfDayOfMonthBetween(start1, end1)); // 3

    LocalDate start2 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 31);
    LocalDate end2 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MAY, 28);
    System.out.println(getCountOfDayOfMonthBetween(start2, end2)); // 2
}
```

Comment: I ran your previous implementation, so if I consider Jan 31 2019 to May 31 2019, this still gives me a count of 4. This should give me a count of 2 right. I have updated your code a little bit to get the desired output. Look at my comment below

Comment: @LifeStartsAtHelloWorld Edited again. I think it should be good now. If this answered your question then please accept as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getCountOfDayOfMonthBetween(int dayOfMonth, LocalDate scheduleStartDate, LocalDate scheduleEndDate) {

    if(scheduleEndDate == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    LocalDate currDate = scheduleStartDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);

    LocalDate convertedDate = scheduleStartDate.withDayOfMonth(
            scheduleStartDate.getMonth().length(scheduleStartDate.isLeapYear()));

    int recordCount = 0;
    while (currDate.isBefore(scheduleEndDate)) {

        if(convertedDate.getDayOfMonth() >= scheduleStartDate.getDayOfMonth()) {
            recordCount++;
        }

        currDate = currDate.plusMonths(1);
        convertedDate = convertedDate.plusMonths(1);
        convertedDate = convertedDate.withDayOfMonth(
                convertedDate.getMonth().length(convertedDate.isLeapYear()));
    }
    return recordCount;
}
```